# How do you use ruby's WIN32OLE to get an instance of a non "IDispatch" interface?

Tags: ruby, com, win32ole

I want to access the CUIAutomation object via Ruby. OLE/COM object viewer reports the following details:

```
[
  uuid(FF48DBA4-60EF-4201-AA87-54103EEF594E),
  version(1.0),
  helpstring("The Central Class for UIAutomation")
]
coclass CUIAutomation {
    [default] interface IUIAutomation;
};
```

I tried accessing it using the UUID

```
 WIN32OLE.new('{FF48DBA4-60EF-4201-AA87-54103EEF594E}')
WIN32OLERuntimeError: failed to create WIN32OLE object from `{FF48DBA4-60EF-4201-AA87-54103EEF594E}'
    HRESULT error code:0x80004002
      No such interface supported
```

Looking at the implementation of [WIN3OLE.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html#method-c-new) it attempts to grab the IDispatch interface, but fails.

```
...
/* get IDispatch interface */
hr = CoCreateInstance(&clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER,
                      &IID_IDispatch, &p);
...
```

In the [Microsoft examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384838%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the code uses the IID_IUIAutomation interface directly

```
#include <uiautomation.h>

// CoInitialize must be called before calling this function, and the  
// caller must release the returned pointer when finished with it.
// 
HRESULT InitializeUIAutomation(IUIAutomation **ppAutomation)
{
    return CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, 
        reinterpret_cast<void**>(ppAutomation));
}
```

Do I need to patch and rebuild Win32OLE? How else can I get an instance of CUIAutomation?

Comment: Seems I am not the first person to have this problem https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/217965

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - you don't.  Win32Ole requires the capabilities that IDispatch provides. If a COM object does not expose access to IDispatch then it is not compatible with Win32Ole.  The only option would be to develop your own IDispatch wrapper using another language, like C/C++, and then you can use that with Win32Ole.

Comment: I've had a quick look at https://github.com/djberg96/pr-win32ole. I reckon I could use this to implement something that calls onto the exposed interface.